# Azure Messaging FILO (First In Last Out)

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

How is First in Last Out(FILO) done in Azure messaging framework? All the articles are pointing to FIFO and azure service bus Queue.

Comment: Can you explain the need in FILO with messaging? What's your use case?

Comment: the latest incidents need to be attended first by a support team(special task force) , remaining will continue as the traditional FIFO way by the traditional support team. This would give a quick response feel to the lucky customer treated by special task force.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do FILO for Azure queues.

Azure has two types of queues

1. Azure Storage Queues - Does not gurantee FIFO
2. Azure Service Bus Queues - Gurantee FIFO

You can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#comparing-storage-queues-and-service-bus-queues) to check the difference between them.

Comment: question is not about azure queues. Or whether azure queues can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Messaging will not provide you what you're looking for.

If you think about it, at any time for any message that is last in a queue there might be another message coming in, throwing off your LIFO order as the N-1 message will be processed first rather than N-th message. You will need a data store to ingest those messages and query in the descending order.